# how to combine two queries having count from different tables and more than one columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have one query that returns  count and some columns from two tables and another query that returns count and a column from two tables.
I want to combine this two queries that results in single row per id.
i have tried this:

```
select 
(select a.column_1 as ID,a.column_2,COUNT(b.column_2) as Cnt1
from
    table_1 a left outer join table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID
group by 
    a.column_1 as ID,a.column_2
)
where EXISTS
(select a.column_1 as ID,COUNT(c.column_2) as Cnt2
from
    table_1 a left outer join table_3 c on a.ID=c.ID
group by
    a.column_1
)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: I want result as ID  column_2  Cnt1  Cnt2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without knowing your real schema...based on your sample query, assuming your inner queries are correct (some minor syntax error).  You might want to do something like this.

```
select *
FROM
  (select a.column_1 as ID,a.column_2,COUNT(b.column_2) as Cnt1
    from table_1 a left outer join table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID
    group by a.column_1,a.column_2
  ) T1
INNER JOIN
  (select a.column_1 as ID,COUNT(c.column_2) as Cnt2
    from table_1 a left outer join table_3 c on a.ID=c.ID
    group by a.column_1
  ) T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/742745/4)

You might want to replace `select *` with `select T1.ID,T1.column_2,Cnt1,Cnt2` based on your comment.